# ACL to change Read Write permissions of another User's files

Tags: files, permissions, acl, read, write

Is there a way that sysadmin can create an ACL(ex: read_write_acl) so that all users which are assigned "read_write_acl" can modify the file permissions (only read and write) for the files and directories which are not owned by them?

Comment: Not via ACLs. I was recently thinking of doing something like this via, a user-mode file-system (fuse). Where the underlying FS is owned by one user, but a fuse FS. Can set present the FS with different modes. I was thinking of this so that the owner of the underlying FS had full control. However in it is a little different. I have not even worked out a solution for my use-case (sorry it is not urgent for me).

Comment: Ok..is there any other way of doing it. ?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor This is of course supported by ACLs. Check the `write_acl` property of ACLs, see `chmod` man page: http://schillix.sourceforge.net/man/man1/chmod.1.html This is in all modern filesystems since approx.15 years.

Comment: @schily I concede that I did no explain my use-case well ( I wanted the original user to keep ownership, no matter what, while granting permissions to others in the group). However if the original poster's use case can be done with ACLs then please add an answer.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Writing a useful answer takes some time that I do not have this week. The basic idea is to set up a directory with the `dir_inherit` and `file inherit` ACLs to propagte inherited deny ACLs for the `write_acl` permission for owner, group and world. This way, every newly created file and directory does not include the permissions to change ACLs, even for the owner. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7530#section-6.2.1 for the related standard. The inherited ACLs may include an aditional special "owner" that has the permission to modify ACLs.